# How to escape ` while answering/asking questions

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

I was just answering a question when I observed the following behavior. I wanted to type something like

```
wget --bind-address=``ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'` ` URL
```

completely inside a code tag but it did not work. I tried using double apostrophe and back-slash apostrophe, but still it did not work. Is there any way to use the code formatting quote as such inside a code block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use the backslash (`\`) character before the backtick (`) to escape it code-formatting your text:

#### Markdown:

```
<code>
=\`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'\` ` URL
</code>
```

#### Rendered:

`` =`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}'` ` URL ``

Comment: Wow! THanks. Never know we could use <code> tag

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
wget --bind-address=`ifconfig eth0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}' ` URL
```

with 4 spaces at line start